# Meaning of "model representation" in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm reading the documentation for the Fortran's "FRACTION" function and I'm confused.  The description says "FRACTION(X) returns the fractional part of the model representation of x.

It then gives an example as such "If 3.0 is a REAL(4) value, FRACTION(3.0) has the value 0.75"

Ummm... huh?! LOL I'm obviously confused on what the "model representation" means. Any guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 3 = 0.75 * (2^2), so the mantissa is 0.75 in a binary (base 2) system.